# Not able to stop hotlink

Tags: htaccess, hotlinking

I am using following htaccess code to stop hot linking my image files

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?article-stack.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
ReWriteRule .*.(png|gif|jpg)$ - [N,F,L]
```

Still the imge of my site are accessible from other sites. how can i stop it?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing an escape for the `.` in your domain name:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?article-stack\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
ReWriteRule .*.(png|gif|jpg)$ - [N,F,L]
```

Comment: If that were the only problem wouldn't that cause the image not to be accessible from his domain, rather than causing it to be accessible from everywhere?

Comment: good observation. But '.' refers to any single char. would it not include '.' char itself? i also support @BenV question

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on my local setup and it worked fine. It's likely that something else in your `.htaccess` is causing this to fail.

I notice that you are rewriting the images to `http://article-stack.com/-` which redirects to another page. It would be best to rewrite to another image or to a 404 error.